# How to access parameter from aws parameter store using function in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-parameter-store

I'm trying to pull a parameter value from the Parameter Store using the following code:

```
 let ssm = new AWS.SecretsManager();
   emailParam = { Path: '/myPath/Service/DestinationEmail'};
   destinationEmail = ssm.getParametersByPath(emailParam, function(err, data){
      if(err){
         console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
         return data;
      }
        });
    }else { 
        destinationEmail = dev.destinationEmail;  
    }
```

I checked the version of the SDk which is running and the console logged out version 2.339.0 so I added this as an explicit reference in package.json dependencies `"aws-sdk": "^2.339.0"`

Whenever I deploy this lambda and perform a test of invoking the lambda I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: ssm.getParametersByPath is not a function at exports.handler
```

Looking at the API documentation the method I have written looks (to me) to be correct but I continue to get this exception.

Any suggestions on how to pull the parameter value out of the store and use if it within the lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the incorrect service. There's [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) and [AWS System Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/features/#Parameter_Store).

You're creating a client for the former, but using the API for the latter. Try using the [`SSM` client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html), I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using the wrong API.

`getParametersByPath` can be found in the [SSM](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParametersByPath-property) class.

Browsing the documentation for [SecretsManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html) reveals no such function.